# Como fazer um get a um post do wordpress aleatoriamente

Tags: php, ajax, json, wordpress

Boas, eu quero buscar um post aleatoriamente dos artigos mas dá me sempre o mesmo artigo.

wp-json/wp/v2/fatos_random?filter[orderby]=rand&per_page=1

Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar a função rand(), informando os parâmetros que você precisa... o exemplo abaixo lista um único item variando de 1 a 15. Aí só vincular o rand à sua variavel `$per_page`

```
rand(1, 15);
```

Documentação fonte:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php

Comment: Mas não há maneira de fazer através do URL se não tenho que carregar os factos todos e só depois escolher um.